# Finding the transposed of the integral-function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transpose

The assignment was to find the transposed of the following function, but I approached it using matrices as I was more familiar with that. I think the point of the assignment was to understand transposed function when we're not necessarily talking about matrices, but here's what I did.

> Let $\int:P_2(\mathbb{R})\to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ be defined by $p(x)\mapsto \int_0^x p(x)dx$. What does the transposed function $\int^T$ do to arbitrary elements?

I rewrote them in a vector representation - for example:
$3x^2+2x+8 \implies \begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\8\end{pmatrix}$

and found the following matrix:

$$[\smallint]_\beta=A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $\beta=(1,x,x^2)$ or $((1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T)$. $A$ maps exactly the vector representations from $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ to the vector representations of their integrals in $P_3(\mathbb{R}).$ Then:

$$A^T=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0  & 0\\
  0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This defines the function $\int^T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\to P_2(\mathbb{R})$, and looking again at what this matrix does, I found the following function: $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\mapsto \frac{a}{3}x^2+\frac{b}{2}x+c$.

In the end I'm not sure if it's correct, I'd expected something like a derivative or something you could write at once using $p(x)\mapsto$ something. Using the matrices might also not be the most elegant, or even correct way.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this using just the functions and no matrices? Is this what the end result must be?

Comment: Could you write down what you mean by the transposed function? I would have expected it to carry the **dual** of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ to the **dual** of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ ...

Comment: To be precise, if $\theta:P_3(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ then $\int^{T}(\theta):P_2(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\int^{T}(\theta)[u]=\theta(\int_{0}^{x} u(s)ds)$. If you do the calculations with the canonical basis and dual basis it checks arithmetically (of course) with what you have done.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Well the whole point is that I don't really completely understand what is meant with a transposed function, but I do know it goes hand-in-hand with the matrix definition. In the question nothing about dual spaces was mentioned, just a polynomial function.

Comment: I believe I  have written down the definition, and what I have written down translates in matrix terms to the transposed matrix.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I looked into it more today and I understand now what you were trying to say, and it was in fact true about the dual spaces. What I didn't realise is that I had an explicit form because I filled in the standard basis vectors, while the form you put it in is more general.